# Sketch3: Change font for multiple elements but keep different font sizes

Tags: fonts, sketch-app

In the below example, a Tag has font Didot and size 48, the below tags have the same font but size 24.

[image]

In Sketch 3 (Version 43.1), can I somehow change the font for both elements (or all text elements) but keep the font size of the elements at once?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by **selecting multiple elements at once** and then selecting the new font from the typeface button on the right-hand side bar, just as you would if you were changing the font of a single element.

To select multiple elements at once, hold own <kbd>shift</kbd> and click on each element once, either on the canvas or on the layers side bar.

The elements will keep their original font size.

Comment: Fine, but then to try out what different fonts look like on the whole design, I every time first need to select all text elements?

Answer (score 0):

I use a plugin called [Fontily](https://github.com/partyka1/Fontily) that finds & replaces all instances of a particular font.